# How can I add an existing test suite to test plan in Test Manager

Tags: tfs, microsoft-test-manager

In TFS 2013 I have a test plan named "Release 6.2".   I also have a test suite named "Sprint 2015-02".  I try to add the test suite to the test plan via Test Manager by selecting the test plan and clicking on the "Add Requirements" button.  I select the test suite from the query results and click on the "Add requirements to plan" button.  When I do, I am returned to the former dialog showing the test plan but the suite does not appear under the plan.  No message of any sort is given.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?  I have noticed that I can create a test suite under the test plan by adding a new one.  If I subsequently remove it from the plan, I cannot add it again using the above method.

Any ideas???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you click Add Requirement you are creating a new Requirement-Based Suite (a suite that dynamically shows all Tests linked to that Requirement).  You can't "add" a Test Suite from another Plan, but you can clone it which should accomplish the same thing (Test Suites can't belong to multiple Test Plans).

Just right click your Test Plan and choose Create Test Suites by Referencing Existing Test Cases.

Comment: Thank you sir.  That was a detail I did not understand.